# Batch Insert using Hibernate: why stats show me a different number of flushed entitites?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, batch-processing

I am new to Spring and Hibernate. I have 157 records and I want to batch insert the records using Hibernate. I created my entity and in my service I am making a list of entities. I am using `CrudRepository.saveAll(List)` to do batch insert.

But Hibernate statistics show me 1045 flushed entities. When I add something to logger to see SQL queries it is exactly 157 statements for this entity. It shows batch size as what I `defined(160)`. I tried different ways like `session.flush` and `session.clear`. All other methods have the same result. It saves 157 records in the database which means the result is correct. Why does it show me 1045 instead of 157? Can I see the number of inserted entities instead?

P.S: It is 158 statements in statistics because one single record is for another entity that is not part of my question.
This is part of my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listsize; i++){
    listFields.add(entity);
}
FieldsDAO.saveAll(listFields);
```

and the screenshot for the report
[spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW11l.png)

My second concern is why it executes both batch and JDBC Statement? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: please ask a question about the first part, don't just describe what's happening

Comment: why entity number is 1045 instead of 157. Why it shows me it is executing jdbc statement while I am doing batch?